# Default fedora 15 install, how do you get a network drive to mount after login?

Tags: fedora, shell-script, sudo, login

I am running a default fedora 15 install. My goal is to have a couple of network drives get mounted right after the user logs in graphically (not via ssh).

The script I want to execute is basically just a bunch of mount commands: `sudo mount ...; sudo mount ...; sudo mount ...;`.

I used `visudo` to let the user have NOPASSWD necessary when doing `sudo mount`.

**Where can I put my simple script so that when the user logs in the script will execute?**

Comment: each user would mount a different network drive... this is why I would like this to happen after login and not at the computer startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should *not* simply allow unfettered access to mount as the superuser using `NOPASSWD`. You should instead create appropriate entries in `/etc/fstab` so that the filesystems can be mounted by unprivileged users.

If you *really* want to do this (you don't), you can do this in `~/.bash_profile` if the users use bash as their shell, otherwise `~/.profile`, or in `/etc/profile` by evalating `$EUID`.

Again, **don't** do that. Just add the fstab entries so that an unprivileged user can mount it without elevating.

Comment: If i put the mount into /etc/fstab, then the user can do on the command line: `mount $NETWORK_DRIVE_NAME`. I thought the user still needs to do 'sudo mount $NETWORK_DRIVE_NAME`?

Comment: Not if you set the mount options correctly. Check the documentation provided by your filesystem.

Comment: "check the documentation provided by your filesystem" is not low-level enough for me to take a next-action on "how can you make mount not require sudo?"...

Comment: and... there's another question that you forced me to ask... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/does-mount-always-require-sudo-priveledge lol.