# How to allow non-superusers to mount any filesystem?

Tags: linux, mount, non-root-user

Is it possible to allow some particular users (e.g. members of a group) to mount **any** filesystem without superuser privileges on Linux?

Another question might have been "in what ways a user can harm a system by mounting filesystems?"

Comment: Maybe [`gvfs-mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-mount.1.html)`-d /dev/sdX`

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/does-mount-always-require-root-privileges

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are a couple approaches, some of them mostly secure, others not at all.

### The insecure way

Let any use run `mount`, e.g., through sudo. You might as well give them root; it's the same thing. The user could mount a filesystem with a suid root copy of `bash`—running that instantly gives root (likely without any logging, beyond the fact that `mount` was run).

Alternatively, a user could mount his own filesystem on top of `/etc`, containing his/her own copy of `/etc/shadow` or `/etc/sudoers`, then obtain root with either `su` or `sudo`. Or possibly bind-mount (`mount --bind`) over one of those two files. Or a new file into `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Similar attacks could be pulled off over `/etc/pam.d` and many other places.

Remember that filesystems need not even be on a device, `-o loop` will mount a file which is owned (and thus modifiable) by the user.

### The mostly secure way: udisks or similar

The various desktop environments have actually already built solutions to this, to allow users to mount removable media. They work by mounting in a subdirectory of `/media` only and by turning off set-user/group-id support via kernel options. Options here include `udisks`, `udisks2`, `pmount`, `usbmount`,

If you must, you could write your own script to do something similar, and invoke it through sudo—but you have to be really careful writing this script to not leave root exploits. If you don't want your users to have to remember sudo, you can do something like this in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $UID -ne 0 ]; then       # or `id -u`
    exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"
fi

# rest of script goes here
```

### The will-be-secure someday way: user namespaces

Linux namespaces are a very lightweight form of virtualization (containers, to be more specific). In particular, with user namespaces, *any* user on the system can create their own environment in which they are root. This would allow them to mount filesystems, except that has been explicitly blocked except for a few virtual filesystems. Eventually, FUSE filesystems will probably be allowed, but the [most recent patches I could find](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg1631371.html) don't cover block devices, only things like sshfs.

Further, many distro kernels have (for security reasons) defaulted to not allowing unprivileged users to use user namespaces; for example [Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712870) has a `kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone` that defaults to 0. Other distros have similar settings, though often with slightly different names.

The best documentation I know of about user namespaces is an LWN article 
*[Namespaces in operation, part 5: User namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/532593/).*

For now, I'd go with udisks2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! BTW, would you reckon it is secure to allow users in the group `mount` to be able to mount filesystems like root does?  I will read the namespaces document you've linked, and try to implement this mount group thing, at least as an exercise.

Comment: @gkya I hope my first section has made it clear that allowing (a) mounting a filesystem without forcing nosuid [and also nodev]; or (b) at an arbitrary location is basically giving root. If you give someone permission to run arbitrary `mount` commands, that's the same as giving root.

Comment: @gkya from your "many removable drives with many partitions on each" comment on another answer, I'd guess you want the "udisks or similar" approach.

Comment: @derobert since you were talking about user namespaces, you may want to check out Plan 9 from Bell Labs (it's the successor to UNIX, made by the same people). it models the file tree as a per-process namespace (and there's no such thing as root). fascinating stuff.

Comment: @derobert Can we get an update on the "**The will-be-secure someday way: user namespaces**" section?

Comment: @malan OK, I've updated it. If anything, I think using user namespaces for this looks to be even further into the future.

Comment: @derobert How sad. I read the answer, saw it was from 2015, and thought "I wonder if we have this now!"

Answer (score 31):

You can do it, but you need to modify the entry in `/etc/fstab` corresponding to the filesystem you want to mount, adding the flag `user` to this entry. Non-privilege users would then be able to mount it.

See [`man mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for more details.

Comment: This is the only answer I can find with googling.  I have found out that on FreeBSD, one can allow users to mount filesystems with setting a variable (namely `vfs.usermount`).  I want sth. analogous to that.  I use many removable drives with many partitions on each and it would be cumbersome to add a dozen or two entries to fstab for each of them.

Comment: Ugly workaround could be to let `udev` manage the entries as new devices appear and disappear.

Comment: i have not found this to work on Mint or Ubuntu. Yes, the default user account can mount without root, but 'standard'/'desktop' users cannot mount it.

Comment: The `users` option might be useful too.

Answer (score 10):

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks) is the wiki for configuring **polkit** rules for **udisks/udisks2** in order to mount partitions by non-root (e.g. users) group.

Save the code below to **/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/50-udisks.rules**

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  var YES = polkit.Result.YES;
  var permission = {
    // only required for udisks1:
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount-system-internal": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.luks-unlock": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-eject": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-detach": YES,
    // only required for udisks2:
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.power-off-drive": YES,
    // required for udisks2 if using udiskie from another seat (e.g. systemd):
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-other-seat": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media-other-seat": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.power-off-drive-other-seat": YES
  };
  if (subject.isInGroup("users")) {
    return permission[action.id];
  }
});
```

Assume you are in the "users" group, using the following command to mount a partition (no need sudo).

```
# udisks2
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda1

# udisks
udisks --mount /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Seems like the way to go but did not work for me.

Comment: How do I make this work on 18.04? I've read that `.conf` files require polkit 0.106, while Ubuntu 18.04 ships 0.105.

Comment: worked for me. I was trying to mount partitions in Dolphin(Fedora 31,KDE) and getting password prompt. I just replaced 'users' with 'wheel'. If you are in storage group, you can write 'storage' there.

Answer (score 7):

## 1 Look where it works

On Xubuntu it works out of the box to mount and eject USB mass storage, hard disk partitions, CD/DVDs and probably more.

Let's assume that the solution Ubuntu chose, using policyKit, is secure enough.

## 2 Pick the relevant part

On XFCE on Debian 8.3 I needed to allow user to mount and eject filesystems from thunar without password.  What worked for me is to cherry-pick a permission file from Ubuntu.

Adding the lines below as root to a file named `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` should do the trick:

```
[Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;
ResultActive=yes
```

## 3 Profit!

(What I did actually was pick a little more from the file with same name on Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked for me. If you need it, it mostly looks like the content of https://gist.github.com/kafene/5b4aa4ebbd9229fa2e73 )

Comment: Only this works in debian like systems, don't know why putting rules on /etc/ didn't work.

Comment: Does not work on debian stretch.

Comment: Works on Debian Buster on XFCE! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can configure `sudo` to allow a set of users to run the `mount` command.

**Update**: as to how you can damage a system by mounting? For example, you can create a setuid root shell on a filesystem which you can then mount and execute to get root privileges.

Comment: I have thought of this, but won't this require the user to run the command with `sudo`?  Also, isn't it the root user mounting the file system, only behind the scenes, with this method?

Comment: Yes, they would need sudo and yes it would run in the name of root. To solve the first issue, you could alias `mount` to `sudo mount` or use a wrapper script.

Comment: What I would like to have is to mount the filesystem without the agency of the root user.  Masking this agency with anything is not what I'm after at all.

Comment: Note that even adding `user` to fstab only works because `mount` is setuid root. The kernel is checking for root or `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability so you can't really get around involving root.

Comment: You can configure, how?  This doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

**`guestmount` libguestfs trickery**

```
sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools

# Workarounds for Ubuntu 18.04 bugs.
# https://serverfault.com/questions/246835/convert-directory-to-qemu-kvm-virtual-disk-image/916697#916697
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/.guestfs-*
echo dash | sudo tee /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/zz-dash-packages
sudo chmod +r /boot/vmlinuz-*

# Create a test image.
mkdir sysroot
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sysroot/myfile bs=1024 count=1024
virt-make-fs --format=raw --type=ext2 sysroot sysroot.ext2

# Mount it, have fun, unmount!
mkdir -p mnt
# /dev/sda becuase we have a raw filesystem.
guestmount -a sysroot.ext2.qcow2 -m /dev/sda mnt
cmp sysroot/myfile mnt/myfile
guestunmount mnt
```

Relies on:

- userland implementation of the filesystems
- FUSE

Docs: http://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, libguestfs-tools 1:1.36.13-1ubuntu3.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple secure way without sudo, acl, etc...

Look for to which group device file belongs to

```
ls -l /dev/sda2                                                                                                                                                                
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  /dev/sda2
```

Saw that device file belongs to group `disk`

Now add our user to group `disk`

```
usermod -G disk -a username
```

And now in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda2   /mnt/backups    ext4    noauto,group,suid,dev,async      0   2
```

or with UUID

```
UUID=c90324c1-3fba-119c-913c-5f913afdca8b   /mnt/backups    ext4    noauto,group,suid,dev,async      0   2
```

Now all users in group `disk`, for now it's only `username`, can mount certain disk.

Comment: disk group membership give access to all disks on system, better to set group membership on mount point aka /mnt/backups but then you have to be root to mount.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in parenthesis, since a filesystem is a placeholder for files, then a user can potentially carry out harmful operations on that filesystem, such as delete files.

Summarising the other 2 questions I will say this:

- `fstab` is great for mounting at **boot** time **permanent** storage. It is not so great when you want to plug in usb drives or mount occasionally some network shares.
- `sudo mount` is also alright if you are on ubuntu* systems. You will still need to type in a password though.
- `udev` will take care of mounting things like usb sticks, cameras and flash cards in ubuntu* systems (but not in less user friendly distros like debian, slackware, etc)

I'll add that, historically, the unix way to give authority to some users (or groups) to do stuff is through the `sudoers` file.

There are MANY guides to use it out there so I will not suggest any particular. I will say that I used the Linux documentation project website to learn about it.

What is more with `sudoers` is that you can mount devices and shares transparently - even without providing a password if you choose to do so (be extra careful about that).

What I usually do in a control environment is I use `sudoers` file to allow users of certain group to mount network shares transparently. So I add the commands `mount.nfs` and `mount.cifs` in the sudoers file that allowing operations such as "mount the home folder of user from a network file server, when the user logs on to a client terminal" and studd like that.

Comment: If you're using sudo to let user's mount their home folders upon login, you should look at autofs.

Comment: I use these together; I could not figure out how to use `autofs` on its own to mount the `/home/$USER` from the fileserver, to the location `/home/$USER/fromFS/` on the client pc.

Answer (score 0):

I'am on ubuntu 22.04

My root mount in fstab is like this: UUID=myuuid / ext4 errors=remount-ro,user=owner 0 1

So, i dont have a owner user into passwd conf file, but i think this owner is the absolute owner of the mount point (directory) ... / has root owner /home/whateveruser has whateveruser owner /media/myuser/mypendrive has myuser owner

We dont need to specify user=listofusers. Owner is sufficient to get root and effective logged user(s)

My usb 3.0 pendrive is getting almost 200 MB transfer rate, after i set user=owner at / ext4 mount point.

I dont know if that works like i said, but i can boot with no mount errors nor systemd errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we could use this options:

user=owner  (root, disk, whatever directory owner)
and/or
group=owner (root, disk, whatever directory owner)

owner is whatever authenticated user from group(x)

we know / is owned by root
/home/myuser us owned by myuser
etc ...

Mounting respecting individual directory permissions match

Comment: we have to match mount point owner with directory owner ;)

owner user|group