# How do you add `cap_sys_admin` permissions to user in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, permissions, pam

I tried adding `cap_sys_admin` permissions to user myroot.

For this, I added these lines to `/etc/security/capabilities`:

```
cap_sys_admin myroot
none *
```

and this line to `/etc/pam.d/su`:

```
auth            required        pam_cap.so
```

But user myroot doesn't have these permissions.

What can I do to add these permissions to my user?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the file is called `/etc/security/capability.conf` not `/etc/security/capabilities`. I was able to get this working like so:

```
$ cat /etc/security/capability.conf
cap_sys_admin   user1
```

And then adding `pam_cap.so` to PAM. **NOTE:** It's imperative that `pam_cap.so` come before the `pam_rootok.so` line.

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/su
#%PAM-1.0
auth        optional    pam_cap.so
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
...
...
```

#### Example

Here with the above in place if I run the following `su` command:

```
$ su - user1
```

I can verify this user's capabilities:

```
$ capsh --print
Current: = cap_sys_admin+i
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,35,36
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
uid=1001(user1)
gid=1001(user1)
groups=1001(user1)
```

The key line in that output:

> Current: = cap_sys_admin+i

#### Packages

This was done on a CentOS 7.x box. I had these packages installed pertaining to capabilities:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep libcap
libcap-ng-utils-0.7.5-4.el7.x86_64
libcap-2.22-9.el7.x86_64
libcap-ng-0.7.5-4.el7.x86_64
```

They provide the following useful tools when dealing with capabilities:

```
$ rpm -ql libcap-ng-utils | grep /bin/
/usr/bin/captest
/usr/bin/filecap
/usr/bin/netcap
/usr/bin/pscap

$ rpm -ql libcap | grep /sbin/
/usr/sbin/capsh
/usr/sbin/getcap
/usr/sbin/getpcaps
/usr/sbin/setcap
```

**NOTE:** See the respective man pages for these tools if you need more info on their usage.

#### References

- [Is it possible to configure Linux capabilities per user? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user)
- [Linux Kernel Capabilities Explained](https://dzone.com/articles/linux-kernel-capabilities-explained)
- [How can I get capabilities to work with su?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614054/how-can-i-get-capabilities-to-work-with-su)
- [Restricting and granting capabilities](http://blog.siphos.be/2013/05/restricting-and-granting-capabilities/)

Comment: Tnx a lot! It solved my problem!

Comment: On Debian, the package `libpam-cap` is required.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :-(