# Perf permission for users other than root

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, perf

I don't know why user is not able to collect perf stat for a service (nginx process which has been started by sudo). As you can see the kernel and perf versions match.

```
$ uname -r
4.19.125
$ which perf
/home/mahmood/bin/perf
$ /home/mahmood/bin/perf --version
perf version 4.19.125
```

But when I run `perf record -e cycles:u -j any,u -a -o perf.data -p 4018`, I get this error

```
Warning:
PID/TID switch overriding SYSTEM
Error:
You may not have permission to collect stats.

Consider tweaking /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid,
which controls use of the performance events system by
unprivileged users (without CAP_SYS_ADMIN).

The current value is -1:

  -1: Allow use of (almost) all events by all users
      Ignore mlock limit after perf_event_mlock_kb without CAP_IPC_LOCK
>= 0: Disallow ftrace function tracepoint by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN
      Disallow raw tracepoint access by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN
>= 1: Disallow CPU event access by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN
>= 2: Disallow kernel profiling by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN

To make this setting permanent, edit /etc/sysctl.conf too, e.g.:

        kernel.perf_event_paranoid = -1
```

It clearly states that the value is -1 and -1 allows collection of data by all users.

So, how can I fix that?

Comment: Read `man capabites` and endow your userid with `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @waltinator

> Read man capabites and endow your userid with **`CAP_SYS_ADMIN`**

refers to [capabilities(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), which currently says this:

> **`CAP_PERFMON`** (since Linux 5.8)
> Employ various performance-monitoring mechanisms, including:
>
> - call perf_event_open(2);
> - employ various BPF operations that have performance implications.
>
> This capability was added in [Linux 5.8](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/08/linux-5-8-kernel-features) to separate out
> performance monitoring functionality from the overloaded
> **`CAP_SYS_ADMIN`** capability.  See also the kernel source file
> [**`Documentation/admin-guide/perf-security.rst`**](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a15cb2c1658417f9e8c7e84fe5d6ee0b63cbb9b0/Documentation/admin-guide/perf-security.rst).

That doesn't go into detail explaining **how** to do this, but gives a list of programs at the end, including [`getcap`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/getcap.8.html) and [`setcap`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/setcap.8.html) which can be used to inspect the capabilities added to a given file and to modify the capabilities.

OP's question is tagged for Ubuntu (i.e., Debian).  For some other systems, there may be configuration files which apply these settings, e.g., [*How do you add `cap_sys_admin` permissions to user in CentOS 7?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454708/how-do-you-add-cap-sys-admin-permissions-to-user-in-centos-7), but in Debian, etc., that is normally done via the package install-scripts.

For example, Ubuntu 18.04 has this from running `getcap /usr/bin/*`:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon = cap_ipc_lock+ep                                 
/usr/bin/mtr-packet = cap_net_raw+ep
```

`mtr-tiny` is part of `mtr`, and the [package files](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mtr/0.92-1) for that include its `postinstall` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$1" = configure ]; then
    # If setcap is installed, try setting cap_net_raw+ep,
    # which allows us to install our binaries without the setuid
    # bit.
    if command -v setcap > /dev/null; then
        if ! setcap cap_net_raw+ep /usr/bin/mtr-packet; then
            echo "Setcap failed on /usr/bin/mtr-packet, falling back to setuid" >&2
            chmod u+s /usr/bin/mtr-packet
        fi
    else
        echo "Setcap is not installed, falling back to setuid" >&2
        chmod u+s /usr/bin/mtr-packet
    fi
fi

#DEBHELPER#

exit 0
```

In the pertinent command

```
setcap cap_net_raw+ep /usr/bin/mtr-packet
```

the `cap_net_raw` should be obvious.  That **`ep`** is less apparent.  Looking at the [source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morgan/libcap.git/tree/progs/setcap.c#n183)

```
        printf("%s differs in [%s%s%s]\n", *argv,
           CAP_DIFFERS(cmp, CAP_PERMITTED) ? "p" : "",
           CAP_DIFFERS(cmp, CAP_INHERITABLE) ? "i" : "",
           CAP_DIFFERS(cmp, CAP_EFFECTIVE) ? "e" : "");
```

helps clarify this paragraph in [cap_to_text(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/cap_to_text.3.html):

> Each  clause  consists  of a list of comma-separated capability names (or the word **`all`**),
> followed by an action-list.  An action-list consists of a sequence of operator flag pairs.
> Legal  operators are: **`=`**, **'+'**, and **`-`**.  Legal flags are: **`e`**, **`i`**, and **`p`**.  These flags
> are case-sensitive and specify the Effective, Inheritable and Permitted sets respectively.

In short, you'd use `setcap` for adding whatever capabilities are needed with the kernel you're using to the **`perf`** program file, with the appropriate flags.

Answer (score -1):

Just using **sudo** before **perf** resolve this for me

```
sudo perf record -e cycles:u -j any,u -a -o perf.data -p 4018
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't answer the question asked by the OP